# Ubuntu 20.0.4 - Fn-Key and Num-key not working any more on ThinkPad E15 AMD

Tags: 20.04, thinkpad, mate

Hy there,

since 2 wekk I have a brandnew Lenovo Thinkpad E15 and decided to give Ubuntu Mate a try. But today suddenly all kind of strange problems started to happen:

1. My Fn-key doesn't wor anymore
2. Num-key and num-block not working anymore
3. Fn controlls on the top of the keyboard not working anymore

What's going on here. Is this something I can fix somehow? Please help.

BR,
Mic

Comment: That looks like a keyboard layout problem. Please check your keyboard layout and modify the title to be more concise. I. E. Fn-Key and Num-key not working any more.

Comment: You have to suspend your notebook once after reboot and it will work. Here is a workaround guide: https://rd.nz/2020/10/installing-ubuntu-linux-on-the-lenovo-thinkpad-e14-gen-2-amd and here the informative lenovo thread: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Linux-Fn-keys-not-working-Thinkpad-E14-AMD-Gen-2/m-p/5027791?page=6

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are on a latest Kernel (install Ubuntu MATE 20.10 or enable the hardware enablement stack or reinstall Ubuntu MATE 20.04.2)
2. Automatically suspend on every boot using crontab:

   - Edit crontab: `sudo crontab -e`
   - put this line in the file: `@reboot sudo rtcwake -m mem -s 2`
3. READY.

***further reading, sources:***

[stackexchange duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602355/thinkpad-fn-keys-only-working-after-suspend)
[E14 Linux guide](https://rd.nz/2020/10/installing-ubuntu-linux-on-the-lenovo-thinkpad-e14-gen-2-amd)
[Lenovo Forum Topic](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-11e-Windows-13-E-and-Edge-series-Laptops/Thinkpad-E14-Gen-2-AMD-freezes/m-p/5052090?page=1#5232857)